# Format string by adding a space before each uppercase letter

Tags: python, regex

I have a string: `HotelCityClass`. I want to add a space in-between each Uppercase letter (apart from the first). i.e. `Hotel City Class`.

I have tried using re

> re.sub(r'[A-Z]', '', str_name)

But this only replaces each uppercase. Is `re` the correct, fast approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookahead regex:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(ur'(?!^)(?=[A-Z])', re.MULTILINE)
str = u"HotelCityClass"

result = re.sub(regex, " ", str)
```

**Output:**

```
Hotel City Class
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vG8rA4/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?!^)      # negative lookahead to assert that we are not at start
(?=[A-Z])  # positive lookahead to assert that next position is an uppercase letter
```

Replacement is just by a space if above assertions pass.

Comment: `r` used for raw strings and `u` is for unicode support.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to deal with CaMeL words, you can use the following regex:

```
([a-z])([A-Z])
```

It captures a lowercase letter and the following uppercase one and then in the replacement, we can add the back-references to the captured groups (`\1` and `\2`).

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'([a-z])([A-Z])')
test_str = "HotelCityClass"
result = re.sub(p, r"\1 \2", test_str)
print(result)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/YnNpzy)

Note that in case you want to just insert a space before any capitalized word that is not preceded with a whitespace,  I'd use

```
p = re.compile(r'(\S)([A-Z])')
result = re.sub(p, r"\1 \2", test_str)
```

See [another IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Cj9Do5)

I would not use any look-aheads here since they are always hampering performance (although in this case, the impact is too small).

Comment: Speaking about "fast": [`(?!^)(?=[A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/wQ8oW2/1) requires 75 steps to find all matches in HotelCityClass, and it takes [my `(\S)([A-Z])` regex](https://regex101.com/r/wQ8oW2/2) 66 steps only. Certainly it is not a means of measuring speed, but a general idea of how a certain regex performs with a given input.

Answer (score 3):

Another one through non-word boundary `\B` which matches between two word characters and two non-word characters.

```
>>> s = 'HotelCityClass'
>>> re.sub(r'\B([A-Z])', r' \1', s)
'Hotel City Class'
>>> re.sub(r'\B(?=[A-Z])', r' ', s)
'Hotel City Class'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clear way to do this:

```
import re
a = 'HotelCityClass'
b = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', a)

c = ' '.join(b)

print(c)
```

Comment: @stribizhev sorry, I mean `b` :P

Comment: what python version is it? `print (*b)` is invalid syntax in 2.7.

Comment: @Alex.S I'm using python 3.4, let me edit my answer :)

Comment: I got it, but it will only work for the current input. Imaging the input string also contains punctuation, numbers, etc. Then, it won't work. However, nice trick.

Comment: @stribizhev yes, because OP only says that he has a string like `HotelCityClass` :P

Comment: Please don't use a concatenation loop to build a string from a list. Python strings are immutable, so a new destination string has to be allocated _every_ time through the loop. Instead, use the `str.join()` method.

Comment: @PM2Ring That is, I forgot this method! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do your job

```
re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", "HotelCityClass")
>>> 'Hotel City Class'
```